# Sets cell to be readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, handsontable

I am using jquery-handsontable to create a data-grid.

If I make

```
$("#example1grid").handsontable('setDataAtCell', 0, 0,"test")
$("#example1grid").handsontable("setCellReadOnly", 0, 0);
```

It changes the text but then when I click I can edit it. Why?

Here is the test http://jsfiddle.net/z9fYC/59/.
Anyway what about if I want to make all the column number 0 read-only?
​

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does look like a bug. According to the documentation, what you did should work.

Anyways, to workaround, you can define the readonly behavior in a cell by cell basis, like this:

```
$("#example1grid").handsontable({
    rows: 5,
    cols: 6,
    minSpareCols: 1,
    //always keep at least 1 spare row at the right
    minSpareRows: 1,
    //always keep at least 1 spare row at the bottom
    contextMenu: true,
    cells: function(r,c, prop) {
        var cellProperties = {};
        if (r===0 && c===0) cellProperties.readOnly = true;
        return cellProperties;        
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice workaround! Of course for all cells in the first column to be read-only, the **if** statement should be `if (c===0)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

It was a indeed a bug in Handsontable. It is fixed as of version 0.7.3